# Is there a difference between a chelate ligand and a polydentate ligand?

Tags: coordination-compounds

I'm confused because my lecture notes state that chelate ligands are a subset of polydentate ligands.

Comment: That's true. A chelate ligand is necessarily polydentate, but not vice versa.

Answer (score 10):

A chelating ligand should bind more than once to the same metal atom. Therefore, it must be polydentate. However, a regular polydentate ligand does not have to ligate to the same metal, and therefore, it is not necessarily chelating.